# How compilation time is affected with coding style (modular programming etc.)?

Tags: c, microcontroller, codewarrior

I have written simple C code of around 4700 lines in freescale codewarrior in two ways. In both the ways number of lines and content are same. The code contains mostly if else loops. Style 1 takes compiler 40 seconds while Style 2 takes 10 seconds despite the same content. The details of the two styles are as follows:

**Style 1**

Most part of the code is written in a loop which is called each 10ms.

**Style 2**

Same as style 1 except the code is broken into 4-5 functions those are called in the same loop.

***How compiler treats both the styles? Why style 2 takes significantly less time than style 1 ?***

Comment: And how much time does it cost a human reader to read the two source files?

Comment: `if` or `else` are no loop statements.

Comment: The more code there is, the longer it takes to compile but calling functions can mean it may take longer to run.

Comment: The larger extent of code in your Style 1 example may give the compiler more opportunities to apply optimizations, which take time to work out.

Comment: Factors such as the use of separate compilation, incremental compilation, and compiler optimisation may apply, but you have not provided that information. The optimiser will probably have to work harder on large functions.

Comment: I would guess you are using the Eclipse version of Codewarrior. It is horribly slow, simply because it is very poorly made. There is no logical explanation of why it is so slow, other than the fact that it is full of IDE bugs. I would strongly recommend deleting that compiler/IDE and get a useful one instead.

Comment: @Lundin I am using freescale codewarrior 10.5

Comment: Wow. That is either a slow compiler or a slow machine or both. You didn't mention compiler options you're using. Some optimizations are O(n^3) or worse and quirky. So comparatively small changes in the code can have relatively big effects on run time.

Comment: @Sandesh That explains everything. I would strongly recommend to delete that one and get a working 3rd party compiler instead.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis agreed but would the style 2 optimization cause the compilation time to reduce so much (4 times)?